# save javascript Date() object to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, datetime

I want to store JavaScript `Date()` object's value to MySQL database, i have tried with `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` data type but none of them accepting the value of JavaScript `Date()` object's value. But if i am converting date format according to MySQL data type then it is working fine. Is there any way to skip this conversion or it is mandatory to convert before sending to mysql? I am using Express js at server side.

Comment: use varchar for that column

Comment: Is it recommended?

Comment: yes , it is recommended

Comment: it is giving one more extra value after `H:M:S`, See this `2016-10-29 18:03:23.626` here .626 this random digit is coming i don't know from where it is coming ?